# До рамблер почты некорректно доходят вложения

Tags: email

В общем, пытаюсь из своей внутренней рабочей почты отправить письмо через SMTP-клиент на ящик, который находится в rambler. К этому вложению прикладываю *.xlsx файл с название на кириллице.

Проблема в том, что во вложении письма он отображается, как 2.bin, хотя на другие почтовики он приходит корректно. Файл не портится при отправке, так как если переименовать его, то он открывается через Excel корректно.

Если сменить название на латинское, то проблема исчезает... Однако, не понимаю, с чем связано такое трансформация названия... Если бы с кодировкой были бы траблы, то название бы отображалось бы какой-нибудь кракозяброй.

Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Письмо шлю через C# код, где использую либу MailKit,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, провел различные эксперименты и обнаружил, если переслать это же письмо с Outlook, то оно корректно доходит до рамблера.

Оказалось, что дело вот в этом заголовке:

> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=
> "=?utf-8?B?0KHQstC+0LTQvdGL0Lkg0L7RgtGH0LXRgiDQt9CwINCh0LXQvdGC0Y/QsdGA?=
> =?utf-8?B?0YwueGxzeA==?="; size=379865;

Нужно закодировать имя файла в Base64 и указать кодировку и тогда он нормально доходит.

Кстати, Outlook выполняет выравнивание и переносит часть названия файла на другую строчку(несколько упоминаний utf-8 для одного куска и для другого).

Если слать с рамблера на рамблер, то он использует другую кодировку:

> Content-Disposition: attachment;
> filename="=?koi8-r?B?89fPxM7ZyiDP1N7F1CDawSDzxc7U0cLS2C54bHN4?="

Но UTF-8 тоже переваривает.

MailKit'же слал вот так:

> Content-Type:
> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;
> name*0*=utf-8''%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82;
> name*1*=%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8F;
> name*2*=%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8C.xlsx; charset=utf-8 Content-Disposition:
> attachment;
> filename*0*=utf-8''%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82;
> filename*1*=%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82;
> filename*2*=%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8C.xlsx

Наверное, это какой-то стандарт, который рамблер не понимал...